# How does a device discover the Mesh local EID address of all other devices on a thread network

Tags: openthread

How does an application running on a gateway intially discover the Mesh Local EID of all other devices on a Thread network?

Answer (score 1):

The Thread Protocol does not inherently provide a device/endpoint discovery service.  It is possible to use something like multicast ping to solicit responses from all devices in the network, but that is not ideal if you are looking for select endpoints or want additional control over the discovery protocol.  As is typical with IP-based protocols, device/endpoint discovery is often provided by a higher-layer service (e.g. DNS, application, etc.).